# Change page in vaadin router litElement project

Tags: vaadin, lit-element

how can I change the current page without reloading by pressing a button, something like history.push in react.
Is there an analogue in vaadin router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, you want to navigate with normal `<a href="">` links. Vaadin Router will intercept those and update the page content without a reload.

You can also navigate programmatically with `Router.go('path')`.